# Editable DataGrid for asp.net core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I am searching a (bulk) editable datagrid control for asp.net core project, with following constraints:

- user should be able to **paste multiple values at once** (like in Excel), say, I can copy this three numbers and paste it at once in a grid's column:

```
    1
    2
    3
```

- no ribbons, tabs, or other visual controls (but context menu)
- the gird without A, B, C Excel-like column names,
- readonly custom column headers
- editable and also
- readonly columns (calculated values from other cells)
- column values should be loaded and updated in db

something similar to this
https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPNetCore/Demo/Spreadsheet/Overview/

(this one does not allow - or I don't know how to - direct data binding to a DB datasource)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Response part 1:**

Based on your requirement you can use the Syncfusion’s EJ2 Grid control to achieve it. More details on this including online demos can be checked in the below links,

**FT link:** https://www.syncfusion.com/aspnet-core-ui-controls/grid

**Documentation:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/getting-started-core/

**Online demo sample:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/Grid/GridOverview#/material

The details related to achieving the mentioned constraints in this control are provided below,

**Constraint: “No ribbons, tabs, or other visual controls (but context menu)”**

As seen in the above shared demo sample link, the EJ2 Grid does not have any additional visual control like ribbon, tab, etc. and the context menu can be rendered for it. More details on using this functionality can be checked in the below links,

**Context menu documentation:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/context-menu/

**Context menu online sample:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/Grid/ContextMenu#/material

**Constraint: “The grid without A, B, C Excel-like column names and read only custom column headers”**

You can render your own read only column names/column headers by using the headerText property of the Grid column definition. More details on achieving this functionality can be checked in the below links,

**Header text documentation:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/columns/#header-text

**Online demo sample:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/Grid/DefaultFunctionalities#/material

Regards,

Sujith R

Answer (score 1):

**Response part 2:**

Please find the response for achieving the remaining constraints in the EJ2 Grid control below,

**Constraint: “Editable and also read only columns (calculated values from other cells)”**

You can enable CRUD actions in the Grid by using its editSettings property. More details on achieving this functionality can be checked in the below links,

**Grid edit documentation:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/edit/

**Grid edit online sample:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/Grid/InlineEditing#/material

You can also disable editing for particular columns by disabling the allowEditing property in the required column definition. More details on this can be checked in the below documentation link,

**Disable editing documentation:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/edit/#disable-editing-for-particular-column

And for calculating values from other cells, you can use the columns valueAccessor property. More details on achieving this functionality can be checked in the below link,

**Value accessor documentation:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/columns/#valueaccessor

**Constraint: “User could paste multiple values in an editable column”**

You can paste copied values into the Grid columns by copying the required value, selecting the required cell and pressing the ctrl + v key. More details on achieving this functionality can be checked in the below link,

**Paste documentation:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/clipboard/#paste

**Constraint: “Column values should be loaded and updated in db”**

Based on the query we would like to let you know that the EJ2 Grid supports the following in-built adaptors to communicate with the data source in the back-end – URL, OData, ODataV4, Remote Save, Web API and WebMethod adaptor. Each adaptor uses a different way to send and receive requests and response from remote services. They are explained in the below documentation link which you can check for more details,

**Documentation:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/data-binding/#remote-data

**URL adaptor:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/edit/#url-adaptor

If you need to access the data from your db through server controller methods then our suggestion is to use the URL adaptor for it.

Please find the below ASP.NET Core sample prepared based on the above queries for your reference,

**Sample:** https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/GridApplication-1263864030

**Note: A local MDF file is used in the above sample to assign and process the data. So before running the sample, please make sure the connection for this file is established in the server explorer and the correct connection string is provided OrderDbContext.cs file in the application.**

Regards,

Sujith R

Comment: Since the response contained more than 8 reference links, it could not be updated as i did not have enough reputation score. That is why i had split the response into two parts.

Comment: I read from the docs that *"Since the string values are not parsed to number and date type, so when the copied string type cells are pasted to number type cells then it will display as NaN"*... now because the pasted values are mainly numbers that means syncfuction Grid does not meet the criteria of paste functionnality

Comment: Due to the maximum character restrictions that can be updated in the comment, i am splitting the response below into three parts.

Comment: **Response part 1:**                                                                                                     The Syncfusion EJ2 Grid’s paste functionality limitation is that, when you try to paste a string value to a number/date type column then it will be shown as NaN or empty cell respectively (the column type is assigned based on the first column value of your dataSource ).  This is because before pasting a value in the number type column it will be parsed.

Comment: **Response part 2:**                                                                                                       So when a string value is parsed it will return NaN which will therefore be pasted in the cell(you need to paste value is only original type of the column). Similarly when pasting to a date type column it will try to convert the string to Date object which will return an invalid date message so the cell will become empty. This is the case that is mentioned in the limitation section.

Comment: **Response part 3:**                                                                                                       However, this will not cause any problems when you try to paste a number value to a number type column or a date value to a date type column.

You can check this case in the following stackblitz sample prepared for your reference,

**Sample:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/8khvav?file=index.ts

Comment: if the grid presented in the last link example is the same for .net core it sounds interensting. The paste behavior seems to be rather to replace existing values. What if I have a singe row in the table and I paste 5 rows from clipboard?

Comment: Yes, the .Net Core Grid has the same behavior as in the previous stackblitz sample shared. The paste behavior in the Grid works on the basis of selecting the cells and pressing the ctrl + V key. This will paste the copied values on to the corresponding available cells but it will not add new rows when the copied values exceed the available Grid rows. For adding additional rows to the Grid, you need to use the default add functionality which can be checked in the below demo sample link,

**Online demo sample:** https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/Grid/InlineEditing#/material